# jQuery Coverflow plugin does not work in UI 1.8?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, coverflow

The problem is when I updated my jQuery from **1.3** to **1.4.4** with UI from **1.7** to **1.8** the **Coverflow** plugin broke.

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/STEVER/4ALPw/28/

You could switch version of jQ UI and look.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

for new **1.8** UI we should use new variant of **ui.coverflow.js** plugin.

put it here http://svdteam.com/js/jquery/ui/ui.coverflow.js